# Blazor databinding to a javascript web component with complex object from C#

Tags: interop, blazor

I've got a Blazor app that is referencing a custom web component (`<omnibar-navigation>`).

This component has an items property that should be a json object that looks something like this:

```
[{'title':'Home','icon':'places-home-1','url':'/','metadata':null,'items':null}, ...]
```

I'm wondering how to bind a C# complex object to that `items` property.

```cs
var options = new List<Nav> { new Nav { Title = "Home", Icon = "places-home-1", Url = "/" } };
```

Then the binding would be something like this (doesn't work):

```
<omnibar-navigation items="@options">...</omnibar-navigation>
```

A code repo for this problem is here:  https://github.com/dahlsailrunner/blazor-oidc.

The page with the exact problem is here: https://github.com/dahlsailrunner/blazor-oidc/blob/master/Sample.Blazor/Pages/Stencil.razor

The component is imported on the Pages/_Host.cshtml file. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. I noticed also some issues with binding a web component directly via Blazor data binding, especially with the connectedCallback of the web component [which is a kwown issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6218).

But the great thing is:

**If something in Blazor doesn't work, you can always use JavaScript Interop to make it work!**

I've created here a blog post for you that shows how to integrate a web component via JS Interop that has such a property/attribute that takes a complex object: https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2020/02/14/initializing-web-components-in-blazor-via-js-interop/

It also shows how to wrap the web component with a native Blazor component, so that you can bind it just with C#. :-)

Here is a git repo with all the code: https://github.com/thomasclaudiushuber/Blazor-Using-Custom-Web-Component

Happy coding,
Thomas

Comment: Your approach using the JS interop was what I had to use to get this working.  Maybe at some point we'll have some tighter interop that can include these bindings of objects across the C#/JS boundary.  :)  Thanks!!!

Comment: Great it works now, Erik. Yes, indeed, I hope in the future we'll have support for this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to build a component with a Parameter property that receives an IEnumerable of your Nav type.  You just need to deserialize your JSON and bind it to that collection.

Check this gist for how you can deserialize the JSON and bind to the collection in the index.razor file

https://gist.github.com/csharpfritz/c4dcfcc731826822e0764728bbd9d88c

Comment: But I can't build a component for this - it's already done and written in StencilJS.  I need to be able to simply use the existing webcomponent in my Blazor app.  I'll post a github repo with what i'm hoping to achieve tomorrow AM.  Thanks for the quick response!